# Program Just started getting tons of stack overflows with a whole new level of error

Tags: multithreading, stack-overflow, system.reflection

Alright, this is probably the biggest program i have ever written.  I use task in it once so that on first run it will search all available files and folders for certain things.  Everything works...well, did work.  Now when i start the program after adding a few more features in.  It is throwing stack overflow errors on things that never had a problem before.

My first one was right in the begging it threw on a simple return of,

```
return System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments)
```

i changed it to just return

```
public string BaseUpdaterPath { get { return "C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents"; } }
```

and it started working again.

it got alittle further into the program untill it runs a check to see if a specific path exists.

```
if (File.Exists(pathINI))
```

pathini is defined earlier as

```
string pathINI = (BaseProductPath + "\\" + Name + ".ini");
```

and baseproduct is

```
        public string BaseProductPath { get { return BaseUpdaterPath + "\\" + Name; } }
```

these are things that should not be breaking.  My error is this

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

with more investigation turns into this

```
        Source  Evaluation of method System.Exception.get_Source requires calling method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CreateDelegate, which cannot be called in this context.    string
```

I can only imagine this has something to do with threading and the initial search that I am doing if this is the programs first run time.

If i can provide anymore information that i may have overlooked in my details i would be happy to provide it.  I have not seen errors like this before that don't really give you much to go off of.

I may just end up throwing up a splash screen during that initial search if it's going to keep causing problems like this and have the rest of the program wait on that task.

UPDATE

I just stepped through my program starting at different steps and i was able to get past that check it kept kicking it out at.  Then i got to a different if(foo == bar) and visual studio did this strange thing where it popped up a little loading window and said evaluating BAR then killed the program with

```
has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).
```

wtf is going on lmao

Another update incase anyone runs into this.  I have a product preselected when i started up the programming,  i wrote checks in to accommodate this however....it blocked me from being able to see what is really happening.

I disabled some code and let the thing run and after a while i found this little bastard popping up on the console

```
    Exception thrown: 'System.IO.PathTooLongException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.PathTooLongException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.PathTooLongException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.PathTooLongException' in mscorlib.dll
```

now i gotta track that down to wherever the hell it's throwing 5000 times and i should be good to go.

Update again if anyone cares.

I found out that even i caught and threw the exception away it was still getting stackoverflow in windows.old because they have tons of folders and files and i was running out of memory.  My solution at this point is during the recursive file check to just discard anyfolder in windows.old.  Cant think of a better way.

THE EPIC CONCLUSION...I AM A DUMBASS

i was having two properties check eachother

```
        public bool IsInstalled { get
        {
            if (DefaultInstalledpath != null || DefaultInstalledpath != "Not Installed")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

public string DefaultInstalledpath
        {
            get
            {
                        else if(!File.Exists(pathTXT) && IsInstalled == true)
                    {
                        return "Discovering! Please Wait...";
                    }
```

.........

i don't wanna talk about the rabbit hole i just fell down

Comment: Yep, stack overflow is usually due to some sort of "infinite" recursion.

Comment: that is why i thought the error had to be in the discovery of each file and folder because it is a recursive method.  So i thought it had to be there.  oh well, you live and learn right?

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags.